# Unmanaged and Native terms

Tags: c++-cli

Does "native" and "unmanaged" code refer to the same concept! or they are different!

Is there an unmanaged code which is not native!

Comment: It is the same thing.  The term "native" has been gaining ground lately.  Probably because of a bunch of C and C++ programmers that worked too hard on their project to put up with the label "unmanaged".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three modes the C++/CLI compiler can operate in:

- Compiling standard C++ "native types" to machine code (unmanaged)
- Compiling standard C++ "native types" to MSIL (managed)
- Compiling managed types to MSIL (managed)

As you can see, it is possible for standard ISO C++ code to be compiled and executed in the managed environment.

Answer (score 0):

Unmanaged code refers to native code. It means that it's not managed by the .NET Framework.